# Hooks vs Class components

Tags: reactjs

I don't know, do i need to rewrite all my class components if I have plans to update `react` version in the project?

My project have large codebase and rewrite all will be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on your question have in React Docs on [F.A.Q. section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components). :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely Not require. New version is backward compatible.